# What is the most elegant way to assign a new set of many-to-many related tags via association_proxy in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

This is my Flask-SQLAlchemy Declarative code:

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.associationproxy import association_proxy
from my_flask_project import db


tagging = db.Table('tagging',
    db.Column('tag_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('tag.id', ondelete='cascade'),
              primary_key=True),
    db.Column('role_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('role.id', ondelete='cascade'),
              primary_key=True)
)


class Tag(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(100), unique=True, nullable=False)

    def __init__(self, name=None):
        self.name = name


class Role(db.Model):

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id', ondelete='cascade'))
    user = db.relationship('User', backref=db.backref('roles', cascade='all',
                           lazy='dynamic'))
    ...
    tags = db.relationship('Tag', secondary=tagging, cascade='all',
                           backref=db.backref('roles', cascade='all'))
    tag_names = association_proxy('tags', 'name')

    __table_args__ = (
        db.UniqueConstraint('user_id', 'check_id'),
    )
```

I think it's pretty standard many-to-many tagging solution. Now, I'd like to get all tags for a role and set new set of tags to a role.

The first one is pretty easy:

```
print role.tags
print role.tag_names
```

However, the second one made me stumbling upon my Python code all day long :-( I thought I could do this:

```
role.tag_names[:] = ['red', 'blue', 'white']
```

...or at least something similar using `role.tags[:] = ...`, but everything I invented raised many integrity errors, as SQLAlchemy didn't check if there are any existing tags and tried to insert all of them as completely new entities.

My final solution is:

```
# cleanup input
tag_names = set(filter(None, tag_names))

# existings tags to be updated
to_update = [t for t in role.tags if t.name in tag_names]

# existing tags to be added
to_add = list(
    Tag.query.filter(Tag.name.in_(tag_names - set(role.tag_names)))
)

# tags to be created
existing_tags = to_update + to_add
to_create = [Tag(name) for name in tag_names - set([t.name for t in existing_tags])]

# assign new tags
role.tags[:] = existing_tags + to_create

# omitted bonus: find a way how to get rid of orphan tags
```

The question is: Is this really the right solution? Is there any more elegant way how to solve this trivial problem? I thik the whole matter is related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1899984/why-is-sqlalchemy-associationproxy-duplicating-my-tags). Maybe I'm just silly, maybe I'm making things overcomplicated... anyway, thank you for any suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

Actually SQLAlchemy does check if the object exists by calling `Session.merge()`. But it does it by identity — its primary key. The simplest solution is to make `name` primary key and everything will work. Sure, the three tables chain will become redundant in this case unless you are going to add some additional fields into `Tag` (e.g. counter).

Comment: Is there any way to say SQLAlchemy it should look also to unique indexes? I really don't want to make `name` my primary key. It's bad design only for sake of used library.